# Copy all values from a column of one Table to a specific column of another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to copy all values from column course_id of table Student to the column subj_id of table Subject.

```
    Student
-----------------
id      |course_id
----------------
1       |A
2       |B
3       |C
4       |D
```

desired result below:

```
    Subject
-----------------
uniqueid|subj_id
----------------
        |A
        |B
        |C
        |D
```

Below is the query

```
INSERT INTO `Subject`(uniqueid,`subject_id`) values ((SELECT `course_id` FROM `Student`))
```

Note that uniqueid on Subject table is PK, non null, the problem I'm having is query returns more than one result.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I hope now the question has more info.

Comment: Are you adding new récords to te table or updating existing ones?

Comment: @Juan adding new records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`, not `insert . . . values`:

```
INSERT INTO Subject(`subject_id`)
    SELECT `course_id`
    FROM `Student`;
```